# Retrieving images from Firebase storage into recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

How do I retrieve the images via fetching its URL in my Firebase storage using Picasso so it loads into recyclerview holder. I saw this in Picasso but I don't know how to implement it.

`Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(aImage);`

I have also search around but the samples I see are quite different.

Here is the code snippets:

```
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import .......

public class FragSearch extends Fragment {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MsgPack, MessageViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.up_msg, container, false);

    mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycleNView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLinearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mFirebaseAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MsgPack, MessageViewHolder>(
            MsgPack.class,
            R.layout.post_listing,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseReference.child("stackpack"))
    {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, MsgPack model, int position) {

            viewHolder.bText.setText(model.getTopic());
            viewHolder.dText.setText(model.getImageurl());

        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView aText,bText,cText;
    View mView;
    LinearLayout pack;
    ImageView aImage;

    public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mView=v;


        bText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.txtTopic);
        aImage=(ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        /*How do I load retrieve the images via url in my firebase storage using picasso
       */ Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(aImage);
    }
}
}
```

json format

```
{"stackpack" : {
  "imageurl" : "http://firebase.........er23...",
  "topic" : "THANKS"
},   
}
```

msgPack.class

```
.....
public class MsgPack {

private String topic;
private String imageurl;
public MsgPack(){
}
public MsgPackString topic, String imageurl) {   
    this.topic = topic;
    this.imageurl=imageurl;

}

public String getTopic() {
    return topic;
}
public String getImageurl() {
    return imageurl;
}
public void setTopic(String topic) {
    this.topic = topic;
}
public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
    this.imageurl = imageurl;
}
}
```

I simply want to fetch the imageurl(which is a string pointing to a resource in firebase storage) value from the realtime firebase, and my imageview loads up that imageurl -using picasso

Comment: you should do it in the `onBindViewHolder` adapter's method

Comment: Please, How i do it in the onBindViewHolder. Is there a guide I can see to know how i can achieve  this @VladMatvienko

Comment: extend the FirebaseRecycleAdapter, and override onBindViewHolder in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it on the `populateViewHolder` method. Just grab the context from the ImageView:

```
@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, MsgPack model, int position) {
    viewHolder.bText.setText(model.getTopic());
    viewHolder.dText.setText(model.getImageurl());
    Picasso.with(viewHolder.aImage.getContext())
           .load(model.getImageurl())
           .into(viewHolder.aImage);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problems, I am grateful @Rosário Pereira Fernandes